# Interface Builder take 100% cpu after upgrading to OSX10.8 and XCode 4

Tags: macos, interface-builder, xcode3to4

I just upgraded my MacOSX from Snow Leopard to Mountain Lion.
The previous version of my XCode is 3, and after the upgrade of MacOSX, I installed XCode 4 as 
well.

However, when I try to use the new XCode to develop a helloworld-like iphone app, I got this problem. The interface builder process takes 100% cpu and never respond. So for now I cannot do any development job on this computer.

I rebooted the mac and the problem is still there.

Does anyone have ideas why I cannot launch Interface Builder successfully?

Comment: Xcode 4.6 doesn't have IB as a separate app anymore.  It's built into Xcode itself.  Do you mean IB within Xcode or are you running the old IB that's left over from Xcode 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have enough RAM to run 10.8 and Xcode together? I would suggest killing background programs or upgrading your Mac, because Xcode never uses that kind of resources.

Comment: When the interface builder is running, the free memory is still more than 1GB. Will the RAM be the problem? I do not think so... BTW, thanks a lot for your fast reply!

Comment: Yeah, I only got 4GB RAM. It is not enough to run XCode on MacOSX Lion. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please mark this answer as correct then so I get credit for answering you.

Comment: I am facing same problem and I have 8 GB of RAM...